# How to send time value from Postman to my REST api

Tags: spring, rest, datetime, postman

I have a class with a variable of type Date, representing a time

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7181205262894478929L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int productId;

@NotNull()
private String productName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@NotNull()
private Date date;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "hh:mm")
@NotNull()
private Date time;
....
}
```

Now I'm trying CRUD methods on Postman, and when I send

> {
> "productName": "name",
> "date": "2016-03-10",
> "time": "10:29"
> }

I get

> 400 Bad Request

with a description:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

When I try without time, it passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jackson, you can try the following solutions:

### 1. Using a custom `JsonDeserializer`

Define a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html):

```java
public class TimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String date = p.getText();

        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just annotate your `time` attribute with [`@JsonDeserialize`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html):

```java
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "hh:mm")
@JsonDeserialize(using = TimeDeserializer.class)
private Date time;
```

### 2. Using the `@JsonFormat` annotation

Alternativelly, you could try the [`@JsonFormat`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation, instead of creating a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html):

```java
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "hh:mm")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="hh:mm")
private Date time;
```

### One last thing

Is `hh:mm` the format you really want?

`hh` means hours in *1-12 format* while `HH` means hours in *0-23 format*. If you go for the 1-12 format, you could consider using the *AM/PM marker*: `hh:mm a`.

For more details, have a look at the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation.

Comment: It works now. And yes, I wanted HH:mm. Thank You very much! 
But now I have another problem :)
When I post  "time": "10:29", it processes it as 11:29. Do you know maybe why is it so?

Comment: @TamaraB It might be a timezone issue. I think you will need to consider the timezone when deserializing your date/time and store the date in the database using the UTC timezone. Just avoid storing dates in local time (unless you are in the UTC timezone, of course).

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "hh:mm")
@NotNull()
private Date time;
```

instead of

```
@NotNull()
private String time;
```

because you try parse to String value `10:29` not a valid representation for your `time` variable